# Storing date and timezones in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, date, backbone.js, momentjs

I just want a confirmation from the experts. 
I still don't feel confident in what I believe to be the right way of storing and treating dates in such environment.

I'm developing a little app, *just for italian users*.

Basically, they can create a list of *entries*, each having a **creationDate** (I am just interested in the date part, time is not useful in my scenario).

So, the user enters in the "date" form field a date in this format: 22/06/2014 represents the 22th day of June of year 2014. Then, date is parsed like that:

```
entryData.dateEntry = moment( $(form).find('input[name=dateEntry]').val(), 'DD-MM-YYYY' ).toDate();
```

Finally, my entry model is added to a backbone.js collection and stored server-side by Node.js + Express in MongoDB.

Querying Mongo for entries, I see:

**2014-06-21 22:00:00 +0000**

which corresponds to "dateEntry" : Date( 1403388000000 ).

Googling around, I discovered that MongoDB doesn't have the concept of timezone. All dates are stored in UTC and the date object I created before had GMT+2.
But I'm really scared... how will I get back my local timezone's date the easy way?

Next, I'll display entry data in an underscore template, this way:

```
<%= moment(dateEntry).format('DD/MM/YYYY') %>
```

And... voilà! I get my local 'italian' date back: 22/06/2014.

Now, my question: **is that the right way to go?**

The process is: parse dates in local timezone => store in utc => retrieve dates in local timezone. **Is it a common practice?**

I also thought: can't I simply avoid using timezones and storing my local (italian) time as it was utc time (2014-06-22 00:00:00)? **Is that so bad?**

Comment: I set everything up to be UTC front to back (database, server, client communication, ...) with timezones dealt with at the outermost edges of the application. I usually work in Rails so I don't know how things are usually done in the node.js world.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's a common practise to store all timestamps in UTC, and then convert it to specific timezones in the outer layers. A lot of frameworks automatically do that for you, including Rails. Let's say if going forward you start catering to other timezones as well, you will not face any problems because your DB has UTC entries. You will be saved the overhead of timezone conversions.

In case you want to save only dates, you can do that as well, but I don't see any harm in the way you do it currently - save everything in UTC. I am not sure about node.js but there would be some setting where you can specify the timezone (of Italy), and all your conversions will happen automatically. You may find this thread useful:

[How can I set the default timezone in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8083410/how-to-set-default-timezone-in-node-js)

Comment: The problem with this is that some countries use different utc offsets depending the period of the year. This mades necessary to store the UTC offset in order to know the real time that a certain entry was made. For this, it would be helpfull that Mongo could allow for storing not only 'Z' but local time stamps as well.

Comment: I don't think so. UTC is a standard. Do the conversion before storing and save as UTC. Then reconvert it in the timezone you want before displaying. If you desperately want to save local time, save it as a string in mongo db, and convert it to time at application layer.

Comment: I'm doing it the way you mention. I just think that storing the date in local time plus adding the UTC offset (Following iso8601) in a single date field, instead of storing these in two separate fields might better approach.