# momentjs toDate() - timezone gets reset

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am working with momentjs and converting dates to different time zones using `convertedDate = moment().utcOffset(timezone).format()`. This works well but it is a string and I need to transform it to date object.

I've tried `new Date(convertedDate)` and `moment().utcOffset(timezone).toDate()` but that returns my current timezone as a date object. How can I keep the converted timezone?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So I wasn't very far off. The format needs to exclude timezone for it to work. This code finally worked how I needed it to.

`convertedDate = new Date(moment().utcOffset('-4').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'));`

Comment: This is not a good approach.  It relies on the `Date` object's parsing, and it's basically lying about the input being four hours off from local time.  The `Date` object *cannot* represent another time zone.

Answer (score 6):

A cleaner approach to get a native Date object with time according to the timezone, using `moment` would be following:

```
convertedDate = moment.utc(moment.tz(timezone).format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss')).toDate()
```

> PS: assuming two things
>
> - you have imported both `'moment'` and `'moment-timezone'`.
> - value of `timezone` is given like `'Asia/Kolkata'` instead of an offset value

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

I have the same issue. Just get the Date as a string using the same approach that you are using. Let's say your date is, for example: '2018-08-05T10:00:00'.

Now you need the Date object with correct time. To convert String into object without messing around with timezones, Use `getTimezoneOffset`:

```
var date = new Date('2016-08-25T00:00:00')
var userTimezoneOffset = date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000;
new Date(date.getTime() - userTimezoneOffset);
```

`getTimezoneOffset()` will return either negative or positive value. This must be subtracted to work in every location in the world.