# Moment Js UTC to Local Time

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I'm trying to convert UTC time to the local time. I've been following this example from this link: http://jsfiddle.net/FLhpq/4/light/. I can't seem to get the right local output. For example, if its 10: 30 am in here, instead of getting 10:30 ill get 15: 30. Here is my code:

```
var date = moment.utc().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');

var localTime  = moment.utc(date).toDate();

localTime = moment(localTime).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');

console.log("moment: " + localTime);
```

No matter what I do the time always comes out at UTC time. I live in Houston so I know timezone is the issue. I've followed the code in the link but can seem to get the local time. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 373):

To convert UTC time to Local you have to use `moment.local()`.

For more info see [docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc)

#### Example:

```
var date = moment.utc().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');

console.log(date); // 2015-09-13 03:39:27

var stillUtc = moment.utc(date).toDate();
var local = moment(stillUtc).local().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');

console.log(local); // 2015-09-13 09:39:27
```

## Demo:

```js
var date = moment.utc().format();
console.log(date, "- now in UTC"); 

var local = moment.utc(date).local().format();
console.log(local, "- UTC now to local");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: didn't work for me, the time is still 5 hours ahead of my browers time which is correct

Comment: if momentjs is aware of the local timezone, is there a way to retrieve it or is  moment.tz.guess() needed to do this?

Comment: @jEremyB, `moment().format('Z')` and `moment().format('ZZ')` can help you.
Also, take a look at `(new Date()).getTimezoneOffset()` maybe it's enough for you case

Comment: @brianScroggins, be sure to not forget `.utc(date)`. In first part, the line `var local = ...` not having it can be misleading.

Comment: I used moment in nodeJs environment and I had to set the timezone in environment-vars for proper work: TZ='Europe/Vienna'
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9849524/2560683

Answer (score 112):

Try this:

```
let utcTime = "2017-02-02 08:00:13";

var local_date= moment.utc(utcTime).local().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
```

Comment: Specifying the zone in which it was saved worked for me (this answer). Also, found it makes life easier if you always save things in utc then format on the client side.

Comment: This worked in my case where we are saving the time in UTC in our db and only displaying local time on the client. Thanks.

Comment: This answer worked for me. Converting into local time only in the client side.

Answer (score 33):

```
let utcTime = "2017-02-02 08:00:13.567";
var offset = moment().utcOffset();
var localText = moment.utc(utcTime).utcOffset(offset).format("L LT");
```

Try this [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rahim373/L0gcL0td/)

Comment: This works great but why doesn't .local() return the same result?

Comment: this fiddle returns the following result on my computer:
    02/02/2017 8:00 AM (UTC Time)
    02/02/2017 10:00 AM (Local Time)
    02/02/2017 9:00 AM (Local Time another way)

Answer (score 21):

To convert UTC to local time

```
let UTC = moment.utc()
let local = moment(UTC).local()
```

Or you want directly get the local time

```
let local = moment()
```

```js
var UTC = moment.utc()
console.log(UTC.format()); // UTC time

var cLocal = UTC.local()
console.log(cLocal.format()); // Convert UTC time

var local = moment();
console.log(local.format()); // Local time
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 6):

Note: please update the date format accordingly.

#### Format Date

```
   __formatDate: function(myDate){
      var ts = moment.utc(myDate);
      return ts.local().format('D-MMM-Y');
   }
```

#### Format Time

```
  __formatTime: function(myDate){
      var ts = moment.utc(myDate);
      return ts.local().format('HH:mm');
  },
```

Answer (score 6):

This is old question I see, but I didn't really get what I was looking for. I had a UTC datetime which was formatted without timezone. So I had to do this:

```
let utcDatetime = '2021-05-31 10:20:00';
let localDatetime = moment(utcDatetime + '+00:00').local().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
```

Comment: You're a godsend today, this is the part I was missing!

Answer (score 3):

I've written this Codesandbox for a roundtrip from UTC to local time and from local time to UTC. You can change the timezone and the format. Enjoy!

**Full Example on Codesandbox ([DEMO](https://foj57.csb.app/)):**

https://codesandbox.io/s/momentjs-utc-to-local-roundtrip-foj57?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 2):

This is what worked for me, it required moment-tz as well as moment though.

```js
const guess = moment.utc(date).tz(moment.tz.guess());
const correctTimezone = guess.format()
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I do using Intl api:

```
let currentTimeZone = new Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone; // For example: Australia/Sydney
```

this will return a time zone name. Pass this parameter to the following function to get the time

```
let dateTime = new Date(date).toLocaleDateString('en-US',{ timeZone: currentTimeZone, hour12: true});

let time = new Date(date).toLocaleTimeString('en-US',{ timeZone: currentTimeZone, hour12: true});
```

you can also format the time with moment like this:

```
moment(new Date(`${dateTime} ${time}`)).format('YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:ss');
```

Answer (score 1):

**I've created one function which converts all the timezones into local time.**

Requirements:

```
1. npm i moment-timezone

function utcToLocal(utcdateTime, tz) {
    var zone = moment.tz(tz).format("Z") // Actual zone value e:g +5:30
    var zoneValue = zone.replace(/[^0-9: ]/g, "") // Zone value without + - chars
    var operator = zone && zone.split("") && zone.split("")[0] === "-" ? "-" : "+" // operator for addition subtraction
    var localDateTime
    var hours = zoneValue.split(":")[0]
    var minutes = zoneValue.split(":")[1]
    if (operator === "-") {
        localDateTime = moment(utcdateTime).subtract(hours, "hours").subtract(minutes, "minutes").format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")
    } else if (operator) {
        localDateTime = moment(utcdateTime).add(hours, "hours").add(minutes, "minutes").format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")
    } else {
        localDateTime = "Invalid Timezone Operator"
    }
    return localDateTime
}

utcToLocal("2019-11-14 07:15:37", "Asia/Kolkata")

//Returns "2019-11-14 12:45:37"
```

Comment: this worked for me! thank you! I used utcToLocal("2019-11-14 07:15:37", moment.tz.guess())

Answer (score 1):

In DataTables or Grids in react, we can use below.

```
MomentJS.utc(row?.registrationTime).local().format('lll')
```

In Db: [Database Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sL6wz.png)

In Grid:
[Grid Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PANFd.png)