# my date automatically decreases by one javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, date

I have a date in my database, but when I try to display it to the web(i'm using node js), my date automatically decreases by one,

for example :

in data base : `2018-03-06` but when i displaying in to web became `2018-03-05`

i use like this

```
<label id ="start_date" class="view-label col-md-7" for="first-name"><%= new_event.start_date.getUTCDate().substring(0, 10)%></label>
```

Comment: could be a timezone shift- are you sure you are always using UTC?

Comment: use moment.js to increase one day

Comment: @avigil can you tell me how to using UTC?

Comment: @SangramBadi please tell me how

Comment: What is getUTCDate() printing??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32540667/moment-js-utc-to-local-time check this

Comment: @deepeshkumar when i try like this `new_event.start_date.getUTCDate().substring(0, 10)` error new_event.start_date.getUTCDate is not a function

Comment: What is the value and type of *new_event.start_date*? E.g. is it the string "2018-03-06" or is it a Date object created like `new Date("2018-03-06")` or something else? If it's a Date object, *getUTCDate* returns a single number like `6` (i.e. the day number in the month), it doesn't return a date string so doesn't have a *substring* method.