# Moment JS and convert to local time of user

Tags: node.js, timezone, momentjs

Thought I understood how to convert a time stored in our DB to the users local time but seems I do not. When I save the kick off time into my postresql database (On Heroku) it is supplied as `2018-11-14 19:45:00`, I save it as a TIMESTAMP. At the time i save it should I use moment?

Running Heroku logs I have noticed that the server time is `2018-11-14T19:45:00.200076+00:00`, which is UTC ?

Using moment JS in my node app I am carrying out the following

```
fixture.kick_off = 2018-11-14 19:45:00.000000
<%=  moment(fixture.kick_off).local().format('HH:mm A') %>
```

I have had a user from Denmark state that this is showing as 19:45 pm, where as i wanted it to show 20:45 PM as per the time difference

Have I misunderstood something here (very likely)

Thanks

Update

I am now using the below as per Matt's answer

```
<%=  moment.utc(fixture.kick_off).local().format('HH:mm A') %>
```

Following on from Matt's comment around checking the typeof fixture.kick_off, it was returning `object`, have now updated my code to be

```
<%  var kick_off = fixture.kick_off.toString() %>
<%=  moment.utc(kick_off).local().format('HH:mm') %>
```

Which returns the following in the console

```
Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO 
format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable 
across all browsers and versions. Non RFC2822/ISO date formats are discouraged 
and will be removed in an upcoming major release. Please refer to 
http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/ for more info.
Arguments:
[0] _isAMomentObject: true, _isUTC: true, _useUTC: true, _l: undefined, _i: Thu 
Nov 15 2018 19:00:00 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time), _f: undefined, _strict: 
undefined, _locale: [object Object]
Error
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the time stored in your database based on UTC, you simply forgot to tell moment that.  Use `moment.utc(input)` instead of `moment(input)`

```
moment.utc(fixture.kick_off).local().format('HH:mm A')
```

Comment: I knew you would come to my rescue Matt :-) I have just finished reading this too (typical i found it after asking the question) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32540667/moment-js-utc-to-local-time thank you for taking the time to answer, just trying this out now

Comment: hmm, still not working apparently, maybe my issue stems from elsewhere then, Ill investigate and update my question

Comment: Looking at your edit, the question is a but murky now.  If the UTC time is 22:37, then the time in Denmark (UTC+1 on that date) would be 23:37, but you're asking for 20:45?  Can you please clean up your question to be consistent?

Comment: apologies, I have cleaned it up now, the Heroku server time is the same as here in the UK. If this question is still murky, happy to delete it and start again

Comment: Keep in mind that the UK isn't always aligned to UTC.  It does UTC+1 for BST.  But I don't think that's the source of your problem.  Probably multiple things compounding here.  I recommend doing some debugging and make sure that `fixture.kick_off` is really a string with a value like you showed here (you're missing quotation marks though - maybe you don't have a string but something else, like a `Date` object?)

Comment: Oh, aside, but one typically doesn't use AM/PM with a 24-hour clock.  "20:45" (`HH:mm`) or "8:45 PM" (`h:mm A`) make sense, but "20:45 PM" doesn't really.

Comment: You are correct that my date is not a string, but an `object`, if I try and convert to a string I get the `Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format` error. Next step is looking into this

Comment: Yes, you need to know how that object was created in the first place.