# how do I maintain time offsets in moment?

Tags: node.js, date, timezone, momentjs, moment-timezone

I'm trying to add/subtract days from moment time object. However, the problem im having is that the time offset is different then the local time of the server.

in db my time

```
2019-08-14T21:38:50-04:00
```

however, locally I get `+0000`

```
moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm ZZ')
2019-08-15 07:19 +0000
```

so now if I try to convert the time stored in the db

```
moment("2019-08-14T21:38:50-04:00").format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm ZZ')
2019-08-15 01:38 +0000
```

if I use parseZone() I get

```
moment.parseZone("2019-08-14T21:38:50-04:00").format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm ZZ')
2019-08-14 09:38 -0400
```

I also tried manually removing the offset of 4 hours (to balance it out?)

```
moment("2019-08-14T21:38:50-04:00").utcOffset(-240).format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm ZZ')
2019-08-14 09:38 -0400
```

But the value out (after formatting) is always different then in.

**How do I get 2019-08-14T21:38:50-04:00 as the output after I format moment obj back to a string?**

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32540667/moment-js-utc-to-local-time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
moment.parseZone("2019-08-14T21:38:50-04:00").format()
```

or

```
moment.parseZone("2019-08-14T21:38:50-04:00").format(moment.ISO_8601())
```

or

```
moment.parseZone("2019-08-14T21:38:50-04:00").format("YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:ssZ")
```

All of the above will produce `"2019-08-14T21:38:50-04:00"`, the same as the input  string.

The main problem in your third attempt is that you were using `hh` (12-hour clock) instead of `HH` (24-hour clock).