# moment.utc() returning same time at aws

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, momentjs

I have function where I convert local time to UTC time, it works fine locally but when i deploy app on aws, it is no longer working

```
import timezone from "geo-tz";
import moment from "moment-timezone";

const { find } = timezone;
function convertToUtc(time, lon, lat) {
  const timezone = find(lat, lon);

  const date = moment(time, "HHmm").tz(timezone[0]).utc().format("HH:mm");
  return date;
}

export default convertToUtc;
```

and this is where I use this module

```
const user = await User.find({ chatID: res.chat.id });
  const utctime = utc(
    user[0].time,
    res.location.longitude,
    res.location.latitude
  );
  
  await User.find({ chatID: res.chat.id }).update({
    time: utctime,
    location: res.location,
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Using this will convert local time to UTC

```
moment().utc().format()
moment().utc().format('HH:mm')
```

You can also check this [Moment Js UTC to Local Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32540667/moment-js-utc-to-local-time#answer-32540840)