# How set default timezone in node js for windows

Tags: node.js, timezone

I'm trying to set the time zone at the start of the application

```
set "TZ=UTC"
node main.js
```

But is not work:

```
// main.js

var tz = process.env.TZ;
var date = new Date();
console.log(tz, '||', date);
```

> UTC Tue Nov 17 2015 21:41:29 GMT+0300

Comment: Please see if this helps: [How to set default timezone in Node.js](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8083410/3471286)

Comment: @GuiImamura I saw it and tried. But it does not work on windows.

Comment: As from [this link](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/aboututc.html), UTC is a standard, not a timezone

Comment: Were you able to figure out how to get local dev server to be UTC on windows?

Answer (score 5):

I published a small utility called [set-tz](https://www.npmjs.com/package/set-tz) which takes advantage of `tzutil` CLI command. When you call `setTZ()` it effectively changes your PC's timezone so beware-if you kill the process, you'll need to manually revert back after you're done-I am assuming you'r process is short-lived.
If you don't kill your process, it will revert your original timezone back for you.