# Node Js setting for timezone doesn't work

Tags: html, node.js, timezone

I'm running a local server with Node Js. I want to set the timezone for Europe, Rome but it doesn't seem to be working.

I installed: `$ npm install time`

Added this to my code:

```
var time = require('time');
var now = new time.Date();
now.setTimezone("Europe/Rome");
```

But when I use it it shows as (UTC +0):

```
var time = req.body.created_at = new Date().toISOString().replace(/T/, ';').replace(/\..+/, '')+ ';';
```

Comment: It doesn't work like that `Date()` and `time.Date()` are two completely separate objects

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I set the default timezone in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8083410/how-can-i-set-the-default-timezone-in-node-js)