# Node js showing incorrect timezone

Tags: node.js, timezone

I'm having a problem with NodeJS timezone. In my server.js file, i have the code below, but the time does not change to the correct timezone (-3h00)

```
process.env.TZ = 'America/Sao_Paulo';
console.log("Nova Data", new Date());
```

How can i fix this?

[image]

Comment: [THIS](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/11365) is not the answer but may be help to reach the answer

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to set the env before you start the app.

When you change it by process.env zthe change can be seen only by `new Date().toLocaleTimeString()`

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8083410/how-can-i-set-the-default-timezone-in-node-js) answer or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10825813)

Comment: i'm using dotenv lib and configured .env file (TZ=America/Sao_Paulo) and does not work either. What surprises me it's when i print process.env.TZ, it shows the value i want, but timestamp remains incorrect.

Comment: the new date thing works (let date = new Date;
let time = date.toLocaleTimeString();), but how can i change in the entire system ?