# How to set timezone to "-03:00", sequelize cli

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I live in Brazil and i want to change timezone to `-03:00`, but that code doesn't work

File:config.json.

```
"development": {
    "username": "root",
    "password": "",
    "database": "sequelize_cli",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "mysql",
    "operatorsAliases": false,
    "timezone":  "-03:00"
  }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I set the default timezone in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8083410/how-can-i-set-the-default-timezone-in-node-js)

Comment: You can try to set it to `"timezone": "America/Sao_Paulo"` alternatively

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I don't know exactly your type of env like (development, test or production) that you have or not already define. to ensure please check your `./models/index.js`

[image]
[the image of the ./models/index.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79Mgf.png)

in that code you can see on the 7th line that have you ever have an env or not?, and if you didn't have, then the env will be define as `development` for default. but
if you have any env in your code, please ensure the NODE_ENV is `development`