# Make node.js use system timezone

Tags: node.js, datetime, timezone

I have a Docker container with 'Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)' and node.js 8. The system timezone (in `/etc/timezone`) is 'Europe/Moscow' but when I run `node` and type

```
new Date();
```

I get a UTC date, but not a local Moscow date.

How to make node.js use system timezone by default?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/9849524/2153237

Comment: @JoseCarlosRamosCarmenates tried `env TZ='Europe/Amsterdam node` but it does not have an effect (but `process.env.TZ` is defined)

Comment: execute: `date` in the command line, show the output, let's see if the system timezone is correct.

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande Yes it is correct, the output is `Wed Dec 11 21:22:20 MSK 2019` where MSK means Moscow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node.js is using your system's timezone, use the following to check:

```
new Date().toString()
```

When you do: `new Date()`, the output you get is in UTC, this differs from the output you get in Chrome's console, where `new Date().toString()` & `new Date()` gives the same string format. But that doesn't mean it's not using your system timezone. You're getting your current time, converted to UTC

```
console.log(new Date())
```

To confirm set a particular date:

```
console.log(new Date(2019,11,11,15,31,0).toString())
// Wed Dec 11 2019 15:31:00 {YOUR-TIMEZONE}
```