# How to set timezone in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, timezone, locale

I am working on NodeJS project. In local server it picks timezone locale: 'en-IN' and in live Amazaon EC2 server it sets timezone as locale: 'en-US'.

How can I change the local server timezone to from en-IN to en-US?

Comment: what OS do you use?

Comment: @O.Jones I am using ubuntu os

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I set the default timezone in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8083410/how-can-i-set-the-default-timezone-in-node-js)

Comment: Locale and time zone are two different things.

Answer (score 0):

For change timezone you need to change your local systems timezone if you are using ubuntu follow this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuTime