# Date miscalculation on aws EBS server. It's running perfectly fine on local

Tags: javascript, node.js, date-fns

There is always a miscalculation when deployed on aws server.

**Context:**

All the dates stored in mongoDB are in UTC format. And I want to convert the dates to IST before I export them in excel.

My code works perfectly fine on my local machine, but when deployed on server, it fails.

Here is an example that will help understand the issue.

```
const myDate = new Date('2022-12-21T18:41:18.384+00:00');

// The value of convertedDate should be 2022/12/21
// But, it for some reason returns - 2022/12/22
const convertedDate = myDate.toLocaleDateString('en-GB');
```

I also tried to user external library `date-fns` to handle the issue. Following is the sample code:

```
const zonedDate = utcToZonedTime(myDate, 'Asia/Kolkata');

// this is also - 2022/12/22
const convertedDate = formatInTimeZone(zonedDate, 'Asia/Kolkata', 'yyyy-MM-dd');
);
```

Another variation for `date-fns` that I tried was:

```
const zonedDate = utcToZonedTime(
      new Date(myDate.valueOf() + myDate.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000),
      'Asia/Kolkata',
);

// this is also - 2022/12/22
const convertedDate = formatInTimeZone(zonedDate, 'Asia/Kolkata', 'yyyy-MM-dd');
```

**Please note that locally, everything works perfectly fine.**

Comment: You should not need to use `utcToZonedTime` at all. Just pass your original `myDate` into `formatInTimeZone`.

Comment: Change your system timezone to be that of the server (most likely UTC) and you should be able to reproduce the issue locally.

Comment: @Bergi Please post both of these comments as answer so that I can accept these answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I also tried to use external library `date-fns` to handle the issue.

It seems you converted back-and-forth, or even converted twice (for double the timezone offset?). You should not need to use `utcToZonedTime` at all. Just pass your original `myDate` timestamp into `formatInTimeZone`:

```
 const convertedDate = formatInTimeZone(myDate, 'Asia/Kolkata', 'yyyy-MM-dd');
```

> locally, everything works perfectly fine

Change your system timezone to be that of the server (most likely UTC) and you should be able to reproduce the issue. For node.js, [start it with the `TZ` environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8083410/1048572).